# Class-based Views in Django

Tags: django

I'd like to ask you if you can clear something up to me. I'm designing a web app powered by Django and I'm also learning about OOP as I go.

From what understand main purpose of class-based views is to keep my code DRY. To avoid any repetitive or redundant code.

I've tried to implement class-based views however at the end I always ended up tossing everything into function-based view 'coz all the views are fairly unique.

When I looked over the views I asked myself: "Does your code repeat anywhere ?" Answer was no.

The question is: Despite using classed-based views being considered to be the best coding practice it's not always possible. Am I right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class-based views are not inherently better than function-based views.  In many cases it's a matter of preference.  However, as you get further along in Django you will see that many of the features you'll be using are used in the same view (loading a template, for example) and you may find it easier to modify or extend an existing default CBV than writing a brand-new function every time.

Your question will probably be closed as opinion-based, but I recommend taking what you have over to the Code Review Stack Exchange and getting some feedback there.

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/03/21/class-based-views-vs-function-based-views.html

Comment: Yeah ... the render statement is the only line they all have in common.

Comment: Class-based views also let you overwrite a lot of the methods that power them, like get_context_data, form_valid, get_success_url, etc. They may seem overly restrictive at first, but by overwriting what you need to you can have them do anything a function can do.

Comment: @Sam Bobel   That's good point. So it's either make your own function that does what you need it to and nothing more or use a class that is shipped with bunch of functions inside and override function that needs to be overriden. What a pickle.   (pun intended)

Comment: Yes, or override the function and call super to get the default and then add  your own data on top of that. I do that all the time with get_context_data.

Comment: I started with function-based views too; they're definitely easier to wrap your head around.  I'd encourage you to challenge yourself to use a CBV somewhere just for learning sake.  Master both and choose which one you like for a given purpose.

Comment: (also, which I appreciate it, don't accept my answer so fast--there are a lot more knowledgeable people around here who can probably give better or more thorough answers... or contrary opinions)

Comment: I defo want to get grips with CBV. Honestly, I like them better and they look neater to me. I just need to spend more time with them. Cheers.

Comment: Post a use-case here and maybe somebody can give a pointer on how to best do it with CBV